Bringing clarity to status tag usage on meta sites
Let’s talk about the status tags. Every single user who visits a Meta believes status tags mean something. They’re not wrong, of course. But what, really, do the status tags mean? Do users’ beliefs about status tags match how they’re used? What steps do we need to take to ensure status tags are reliably accurate, trustworthy, and clear? Riveting questions like these - and more - await!
This is going to be one of those boring, mechanical posts. I’m going to talk about process, definitions, meanings, reliability, expectations, and all the viscera that enable us to get work done. I’m going to do my best to write well enough that your eyes don’t glaze over, but… I’ve written and read enough of this stuff to know that’s a bit of a vain hope. So instead I’m going to try and impress upon you the importance of this part of our operations, in the hope it will see you through to the end.
To aid understanding, I’m going to write as directly and to-the-point as I can. No fluff, extravagant bonus language, unnecessary tautologies, or redundant prolixity.
Problem we’re trying to solve: Status tags are not consistently used to mean the same thing by all people in all situations. When they are used consistently, users do not necessarily understand them to mean what was intended. Because their definitions are loose, it is also sometimes unclear what status tag should be applied or what changing a status tag is intended to communicate to users. Similarly, we lack clear and appropriate internal guidance on how and when to use status tags.
Goals of this post:

Introduce a proposal for clear status tag definitions.
Introduce a conceptual difference between “process tags,” where staff input is still necessary, and “outcome tags,” where it isn’t.
Clarify when status tags should and shouldn’t be used.
Clarify and refine user/employee expectations (rather than introduce major changes).

Non-goals of this post:

Make commitments about the way we are going to handle posts with process tags (defined below) or commit to perfect usage on a specific timeline.
Develop a public plan for ensuring the correctness of posts with status tags.
Tell moderators how to use status tags.
Provide copy to update tag wikis for status tags. (Feel free to make any changes as appropriate, but this post wasn't written with that in mind.)
Clarify how to interpret status tags on posts predating their modern usage.
Clarify what a user or moderator should do if a status tag is in an erroneous condition.
Achieve perfect clarity for all readers. (It would be nice, but I prefer to set more realistic goals.)


We have eight status tags today. They can be divided into “process tags” and “outcome tags.”
We currently have eight status tags on each per-site meta: status-completed, status-bydesign, status-declined, status-norepro, status-review, status-deferred, status-planned, and status-reproduced.
All of these are actively used, save one – status-reproduced. For reasons that are not relevant to this discussion, usage of status-reproduced has essentially fallen to zero. I’m not going to seek to change that here, and won’t discuss its usage further. (If we’re being honest, this proposal probably kills it implicitly, too). (Small update: I reviewed all the posts in status-reproduced and determined that all of them belong in other states. I retagged all of them, so now usage is actually zero.)
Of the seven remaining tags, they can be divided into two classes:

Process tags serve to indicate that there is a need for staff attention on that report that has not yet been fulfilled.
Outcome tags serve to indicate that the post does not need (or no longer needs) staff attention.

These definitions are mostly complete, bar two scenarios. First, moderators use status tags differently than this - but clarifying this usage is under “non-goals of this post” above, so let’s set that aside.
Second, some folks might object to the language of “outcome tags” here, and those folks would be right to object. We’ve historically told users that tags like status-declined aren’t permanent, and we can / will revisit them as appropriate. This language has introduced substantial user confusion in the way our processes work. While it is technically true that a post in status-declined can later be picked up and worked on, the reality is that users should never expect posts in status-declined to see further work. Exceptions do exist, however, and a pathway must be maintained for a report with a “outcome tag” to regress to a “process tag.” But this should be considered a regression, rather than a designed outcome. In most cases, the standard guidance and process for re-raising declined issues should apply.
Let’s sort the existing tags into bins.



Process tag
Outcome tag




status-review
status-completed


status-planned
status-declined


status-deferred
status-bydesign



status-norepro



We have three process tags and four outcome tags. Posts should never have more than one status tag at a time, whether process or outcome. Any post with multiple status tags is in an erroneous state and must be corrected.
Clearer definitions for each status tag and how it should be interpreted
This section is just tables. No exposition here. The tables are written from an employee’s perspective - from the perspective of someone actually sitting down to use these tags in practice.
Let’s start with the process tags:



Status tag
What it expresses
When to use it
When not to use it




status-review
Staff support is needed to resolve the issue, but the post has not yet been evaluated by staff
Use this tag to move any public report into our internal processes
Do not use this tag if the post as described cannot be handled by existing processes


status-planned
Users should expect a solution to be deployed reasonably soon
Use this tag when we know approximately when work on an issue will finish, e.g. it is in an upcoming sprint
Do not use this tag if the work has not been scheduled, or if the work is speculative and may not ultimately reach a completed state


status-deferred
Staff are interested in solving the problem, but users should not expect a solution soon
Use this tag when we are interested in the proposal but do not currently have resources to complete it
Do not use this tag to avoid sensitive discussion or to ‘soften the blow’ of work we are unlikely to do



And now the outcome tags:



Status tag
What it expresses
When to use it
When not to use it




status-completed (any post type)
We have done all the work we intend to do
We took every action we intend to
An issue resolved without any action on our part


status-declined (feature requests only)
We aren't going to do any work on this request
As far forward as we can determine, we won't work on this request
We see merit, but don't currently have resources to do the work


status-bydesign (bug reports only)
This report reflects intended, designed system behavior
The system is behaving as it was intentionally specified to
We decided a behavior that wasn't originally specified should be accepted


status-norepro (bug reports only)
We cannot reproduce the bug, so cannot fix it
The bug is too transient to evaluate, or not described clearly enough
A simple request for information could enable work on the bug


status-wontfix (bug reports only)
The bug is legitimate, but we won't ever prioritize fixing it
We've decided we will live with the bug as-is
We would eventually like to fix the bug



"Hey, wait, what’s up with that fifth thing? Where did that come from? And why is status-declined only for feature requests?"
Introduce status-wontfix
To develop this plan, I spent a long time in the salt mines, reviewing, reading, retagging, classifying, and evaluating posts. It became obvious from historical context and usage that there is a critical hole in our ability to communicate. (In before “this is just status-declined again” - I promise you I’ve put more thought into it than that!)
Currently, status-declined has an overloaded meaning. In broad strokes, status-declined means that we evaluated the request but decided not to pursue it, generally boiling down to some variation on “we decided it’s not worth it to do.” However, the space of meanings is different for feature requests and bugs.
For feature requests, the meaning includes the possibility that we evaluated the request but did not find that it had enough merit to pursue. In other words, we might (for example) feel that the problem is legitimate, but the request doesn’t solve it, or the reverse - if the problem existed, the request would solve it, but the problem doesn’t actually exist. It can mean that the proposed fix isn’t ready for work and needs longer community discussion or any number of such cases.
Bugs, on the other hand, are either legitimate or not. Either the bug actually takes place, or it does not. If it’s real, then in nearly every case, it would be optimal to fix it. But sometimes, we will choose not to fix a real bug intentionally. (Usually this will happen because the bug is too much work to fix and not really worth the effort.)
This overloaded meaning isn’t terrible, but it does introduce some confusion. What we don’t want is for users to question the legitimacy of the bug report on the basis of a status-declined tag. It obfuscates whether a given status-declined post was declined on its merits or for another more mundane reason. We also want to ensure that the intuitive meanings of the status tags remain relatively clear for staff members.
status-wontfix is intended to address three communications problems:

Allow staff members to simultaneously acknowledge the validity of an issue and move it off their desk if it isn’t worth fixing.
Make it so that status-declined posts have more homogeneous meaning and applicability.
Make it easier for staff in the company to know which status tag applies to bugs intuitively.

How exactly is status-wontfix defined? By contrast! It’s not status-norepro - we must be able to reproduce the issue. It’s not status-bydesign - the system must be behaving in an incorrect or unintended manner. But we’re still not going to work on it for one reason or another. Maybe it’s too expensive to bother fixing, or maybe someone simply drew the eight of swords that day. Regardless, the meaning is far more precise than lumping it into status-declined ever would be. And on the upside, employees are going to know roughly what it means just by looking at it.
Posts normally move between tags along predictable pathways
We can now sketch out some claims about how posts transition between status tags. Posts come to staff attention when a staff member or a moderator applies the status-review tag. This causes a ticket to be created for the post within our internal records. While posts that have never had the status-review tag might still be seen and reviewed by staff, you can only expect posts with status-review to occupy a place in our planning processes or backlog.
(Historically, we’ve asked moderators to use discretion when applying status-review and even provided moderators with lists of topics we are actively working on. While the exact recommended usage of status-review should be expected to change from time to time, our request for moderators to use discretion and best judgment when applying the tag remains. It is worth acknowledging, however, that we have not yet posted new status-review usage guidance during 2024.)
Therefore, when attempting to understand how posts move through our processes, we can and should treat status-review as the universal entry point. Staff can of course be aware of posts without a status-review tag, but posts only enter the process when they receive that tag, thereby creating a paper trail.
With this, we can draft up a quick transition table to describe how posts move through the process:



Process tag
May move to process tag
May move to outcome tag




status-review
status-planned or status-deferred
status-completed, status-declined, status-wontfix, status-norepro, or status-bydesign


status-deferred
status-planned
status-completed, status-declined, or status-wontfix


status-planned
In exceptional cases, planned work that is canceled may return to status-deferred
status-completed only



Notable omission: status-deferred should not normally move to status-bydesign or status-norepro. If the issue is not reproducible or is an intentional part of system design, it should not be deferred, as deferred signals to users that we are (at minimum) interested in working on the request. This does not generally make sense to communicate if we can’t reproduce the bug or if we believe it is by design and does not need to be changed.
Exceptions to this workflow exist, and I will never present the above tables as hard rules that employees or moderators must obey. Sometimes, work is just not going to proceed as expected, or conversations internally are going to fall out of sync with what’s in public, or someone will leave the company with a loose end left over, or someone’s just going to make an earnest mistake, or… the list goes on. However, under normal circumstances, the above transition table should accurately reflect tag changes that take place on the platform.
Note that posts with outcome tags should almost never move, either to another process tag or between outcome states. The two most common cases where this might sometimes happen are:

We originally status-declined a feature request, but later reconsidered (without a more recent post to attach that work to - see the process for re-raising declined requests here).
We originally status-norepro’d a bug, but due to changing circumstances, we can now reproduce that bug.

But these are, and should be, exceptions; I won’t explicitly cover what to do in these situations because these, and other similar exceptions, are all atypical and depend on judgment calls to handle correctly.
Wrapping up: We’re not done here.
Even accounting for status-wontfix, the goal of this post is not to change anything so much that it can’t be recognized. I hope that you’ll see the shape of what’s familiar in the language laid out above, even if it will shift ever so slightly.
This project is a part of the nexus of work surrounding the community asks sprint, and has spun off from our efforts to clean up Stack Exchange’s long public backlog. We hope you see the merit in this change. And if you don’t, we hope that you’re willing to allow us the room to play around with systems to find what works best!
This also shouldn’t be the last time you’ll be hearing from us about how status tags are managed. Just like our recent effort to retag old posts with erroneous status tags, this isn’t a cut-and-run endeavor. Nor is it the only moving piece related to cleaning up how we do work in public. More on this later.
I’m open to small corrections, clarifications, and the like - but I want to say upfront that what I’m really watching out for are serious objections to the plan laid out here. I consider this primarily an internal-facing project, the goal of which is to clarify and render consistent status tag usage by employees network-wide.
I’m also going to request that folks stick to one topic per answer. For a post this involved, managing more than one clarification per comment thread is going to be… a bit challenging. I’ll appreciate your judiciousness here too.
Some of the details might change between now and a final draft, but unless y’all feel I’m about to make a horrifying mistake, this is gonna to be the shape of things. Let me know below!

I know you're not trying to call [tag:status-reproduced]'s validity into question in this post, but... The definitions laid out pretty much kill it. It's probably time to remove it. I cannot find a reasonable usage for it at this time, and the whopping 9 questions tagged with it on Meta SE either should be retagged as completed, or tagged with your proposed wont fix tag. There's no real place for this in the "process tag" section that isn't covered by review, planned or deferred, and it's certainly not an outcome tag.

@Spevacus I'm open to deleting it. Honestly, I can't recall any time during my employment it was even mentioned until now. I'll ask around internally and see if anyone objects.

So can we have moderator-only versions of these that are different colors from the staff ones, since we regularly use these for tag burninations, but by these new definitions (e.g. "doesn't require any involvement from staff") we can't use these for stuff like that anymore?

@TylerH This post does not attempt to proscribe how moderators should use status tags.  (c.f. "Moderators use status tags differently than this - but clarifying this usage is under 'non-goals of this post' above, so let’s set that aside.")

@Slate But... who else is this post for then? If moderators use these tags differently, and staff are the only other people who use them, why is this not posted in an internal staff location? If you want to re-educate regular users on what the tags mean and are saying they should be used in a certain way that differs from how mods use them, that's just going to lead to more confusion, isn't it? Or are you saying that you're going to be making a second post at some point to tackle this issue specifically?

@TylerH This post is for users who want to understand what staff usage of status tags means. If you haven't encountered any problems understanding staff usage of status tags, then - no problem. Inconsistency in status tag usage is a very common report we hear from users and moderators, but I don't expect that everyone will have encountered it before.

My impression is that the tags are indeed being used to mean what they mean. They just aren't being kept anywhere near up to date (and also tons of things that should get looked into haven't been).

One issue at a time, @Karl ;)

This seems like a great proposal to me. Consistent usage of tags is important so it's clear to everyone how staff are using tags; how mods use them is secondary, since these are primarily being handled by staff (aside from mods using [status-review] to escalate feature requests/bug reports for staff attention). This is something I was hoping would get done when I was a CM, so I'm glad to see it didn't fall by the wayside afterwards. Great work! :)

Good to hear that I was mostly on the mark

Is there any appetite for disambiguating the name of [status-review] to [status-needs-review] or [status-under-review]?

@Robotnik Honestly? Doubtful. Don't get me wrong, I'll check, and I agree it needs to happen, but that's actually waaaaay more complicated than it sounds. Involves tag migrations across all sites, [status-review] workflow edits, likely separate comms, and we'd have to figure out what to rename it to that's clearest. (The best thing you can do is to open it as a separate MSE post, which we'll prioritize according to what we have time for.)

@Robotnik Just read your MSU post. Hard to believe you saw that much into what I was doing, and it is uncanny to see you basically sketch out the thought process that led to this proposal. You hit the nail square on the head, damn. My first draft terms were "transitional" and "final," too. Former became "process," for representing in-process work, and the latter became "terminal," then "outcome" to ease the sense of finality.

Good work is self evident :D (aka WE'RE ON TO YOU)

Another thing that might be worth adding to the non-goals - "edit the tag excerpts or wikis" ? When I first read this, it almost seemed like the language could be used to rewrite the tag descriptions. While I think it's worth eventually adding some of these details to the appropriate wikis once final to aid in discovery, since it doesn't address mod usage, it's probably not appropriate to consider these drafts (or even a suggestion to update drafts for) excerpts.

@Catija Good call. Added :)

Could you please summarize all the statuses on one workflow image? It would be great to see transitions between the different states.

@A.L I tried this, but to be completely honest, I couldn't find a good way to display it that I felt would actually help instead of confuse.

@Slate - what's the timeline on the code/style changes announced here (i.e. implementation of [status-wontfix], and removal of [status-reproduced] from the red-tag list). Are they in the current Community Asks sprint?

@Robotnik No, not part of this community asks sprint. I believe it's been rolled into an upcoming process update (internal, but I think we might talk about it). But - not forgotten :)

Somewhat tangential, but since we're talking status tags...
Can we make status tag changes (or any moderator-only tag changes) raise a notification to the author and followers?
Currently, users are not notified when status tags are changed on their post, because tag-only edits don't trigger notifications. However, in most cases, someone adding or changing moderator-only tags on their post is as good as answering the question, and users should be notified when their post changes status.
To quote from this long-standing feature request:

I think it is helpful to know if your bug got fixed, or it was declined to be fixed or wasn't reproduced. While most of the time staff also post an answer or comment when tagging, in some of those cases they don't leave a response, so the user is never notified of the decision.
[...]
To quote Tim Post in a prior discussion:

[The current behavior is] not good design, mostly because it's based on assumptions that we'd leave a response when putting a status tag on something. But practically speaking, that's not always possible, especially when putting status tags on posts closely related to others that warrant receiving them after a bug was fixed, or new functionality, or whatever.


Alternatively, can we make it protocol for moderators and staff members to always post something that triggers a notification - either a comment or answer - when changing a status tag on a post?

I think this is a really fair ask. I always like knowing if my bug reports get fixed/ticketed via status-review. If the engineering buy-in to add a notification on mod-tag edits isn't there, I think getting some personnel buy-in (mods ideally, staff if possible but understandable if not) to post a comment or something would be nice.

This one needs to be its own feature request. If you think the linked post is complete enough, flag it for [status-review], otherwise I'd encourage you to elaborate on their post or write your own request.

@Slate The tag has been added. That said, I do think that the last paragraph of this post is relevant here, as this question has to do with staff protocol when applying status tags, and that's about that.

I appreciate the outline... a small caveat that I'd like to make...
In many cases, I don't really think status-completed makes much sense on discussion questions. This is likely my own nit-picking but a discussion can't be completed. It can have a staff response, which feels like a separate outcome to consider but using that tag on a discussion that's open to anyone on the site tells people that the "discussion" is somehow closed, even if users disagree with the staff response.
For this reason, when discussion questions got a status-review tag and I responded, I just removed the tag and didn't add the status-completed tag. It's fair for y'all to decide to shift how you handle these, I just worry about how using the tag will be interpreted by community members in some situations.
One thing I frequently see is that questions are sometimes directed at staff but given a discussion tag, even if only staff can really answer. A more appropriate option would be to use a support tag in that case, as support questions make more sense with a status-completed tag and if only staff can answer, it's not really a "discussion" - it's a request for the official answer.
Out of curiosity, I looked at the count of questions with both status-completed and discussion tags - there's about 900... which may seem like a lot but when I review those questions, the discussion tag seems like the wrong choice. Many of them are really bugs, support requests, or feature requests that weren't correctly tagged - and if you exclude questions that also have one of those tags, the count drops below 700.
So, I guess one thing I'd recommend is that staff using outcome tags also review the required tag to see if the question was tagged correctly in the first place.
Here's a couple of recent examples of cases where the status-completed is confusing or the question should have been retagged:

Cookie consent going down hill - should have been retagged bug
Does the Code of Conduct prohibit content justifying war crimes? - Status tag is confusing, "staff-answer" might be better or retagging to support
With Stack Overflow Teams moved, where do Meta questions about it belong? - should have been retagged support
Some sites are offline, but no blog or Twitter information. Is all OK? - should have been retagged bug
Please add a corresponding hat for casting downvotes - should have been retagged feature-request
What is the future for Imgur and SE? - should have been retagged support

The bulk of discussion tags I see that get marked completed but don't have a better option than discussion is a group of questions that support the argument for a fifth (staff-only/mod-only ?) required tag - announcements. This includes things like planned maintenance, upcoming changes to the platform, etc.
In the end - failing adding or re-categorizing a few tags - there are situations where it's reasonable for both tags to appear but I support minimizing it as much as possible by:

retagging when the discussion was used in error
avoiding use of status-completed when discussion is appropriate if staff is only adding to the discussion

Hopefully, these seem like reasonable adjustments to this process. I appreciate that staff time is limited but if you're already editing tags, a quick check and adjustment of the existing tags seems like a minimal ask.

Honestly, this is a really solid point, and I'll bring it up internally to see how we want to handle these. I'm not opposed to removing a status tag when it doesn't belong there, and honestly, that's partially what I meant by using status-review on posts that "cannot be handled by existing processes," though I'm realizing that exact wording is ambiguous and needs cleanup. [discussion] posts are a major candidate for this (either to retag out of status-review or clean up and retain).

I'm a bit hesitant to make too big of a carveout exception for [discussions] and generally I'd like to be able to lean on folks' best judgment when they choose to escalate via [status-review]. Mostly because I'm not a huge fan of grey area when evaluating whether we need to respond. It's been a source of confusion in the past. But on the other hand, you are right that some confusion is inevitable and there may need to be a canonical way to manage it. I'll give it some thought, good insight.

Sure, sure! I intentionally avoided touching on complex cases where a discussion gets converted into a FR or somehow needs staff action, such as burninations that involve blocklist requests... the core concept of the question is a discussion but the FR that led to a tag being blocked was kinda built into an answer... making people ask a new question for the actual staff request is an option but can also feel a bit like putting up barriers to GSD. :)

Yeah I feel that. Splitting out independent concerns into their own posts is definitely "the right way." But also (I'm sure you know ;) that doesn't always happen/can be uh, annoying, if we ask for it. And honestly, I think the fragmentation is what gets to people most. "We discussed it here, but requested it there" for sure feels kinda... bad. Tricky to meet people where they are without causing paper trail confusion. At least the grey area is mostly when requests route to Community Management rather than to another team, so... at least we're not shunting the complexity onto other teams. Lol.

Yeah... I think in these cases, it's just a matter of doing whatever's simplest to get the job done – without overcomplicating things from a user standpoint.

I agree with everything here, but I'd also like to add: unlike status tags, required tags can be edited by anyone. I'd recommend any public user should ensure that meta questions are using the appropriate required tag, especially mods when adding a [status-review] tag.

Considering I do a lot of discussion tagged posts that are veiled (large) feature requests, I feel  the 'right' thing here would be to normalise breaking down broad, conceptual discussions into actionable bite sized chunks that are their own posts, and managing them, when it fits into what's on the roadmap and bandwidth is available. Metawise, linked/related posts work. In a helpdesk context, they'd be linked tickets?

@Robotnik Definitely a reasonable thing to ask of mods when they're escalating. :) I've also added the status-review tag myself when I was a CM, so a caveat to the caveat. :P Particularly on MSE, I'd guess there are cases where it's unclear which tag is appropriate, too, such as cases above where someone ends up reporting a bug but they're not certain it is one. There are also some cases where a FR is posted as a discussion to avoid DVs. I think the whole thing can be supported by everyone doing their best to support having tagging align with the question and site expectations.

@JourneymanGeek I don't know if they do it quite the same way but, in the past, when we had a FR sent to the switchboard that relied on a bigger discussion post, we'd actually include the link to the discussion and/or quote the key finding in the core ticket to make it easier to find for whoever picks up the ticket. This was particularly helpful when we got requests to block tags or update UI text that the community had worked on crafting.

I brought your question on [discussion] posts, as well as Thomas Owens' question about [support] posts and policy inquiries in his answer, to the CM team to discuss. Our current opinion is that the [status-review] process isn't specifically designed to support discussions/support requests/policy inquiries, but that in some cases it may currently be the best tool for raising those items to our attention and ensuring it lives on the appropriate team's backlog.

The general consensus was that we need to spend more time determining exactly what our desired pathways are for resolving these issues, because they often have far more nuanced and complicated lifetimes internally than bugs and feature requests.

So I'm going to purposefully leave this case in a grey area for the moment: We aren't (for now) officially supporting the use of [status-review] for discussion/support/policy inquiry posts, but we do acknowledge that [status-review] will sometimes be the best tool currently available for the job. We'd encourage moderators to use heavy discretion when applying the tag in these cases, particularly in the case of policy inquiries, and only apply it when the need is truly compelling.

Is the intent for the status-wontfix tag to remain grey, or will it match the other status tags’ red colour scheme?

status-planned

It'll match the other tags' colors. Grey is for normal tags, and red is for mod/staff-only tags. Currently it's not restricted to mod/staff-only. It will be once formalized.

Yeah, it's currently just gray because it doesn't actually exist yet and isn't set as a mod/staff-only tag. If/when it's set as such a tag, it'll appear like the other status tags.

What about status-reproduced?
While you/we are thinking about the [status-*] tagging process...this tag seems to virtually never get used (9 questions on MSE, and 5 on MSO), and I'm not totally clear whether it's actually useful.
Perhaps it communicates something like "We are aware of the issue, and we have confirmed that we have all the information we need, but further analysis (perhaps regarding the amount of effort required to fix it) is needed to decide whether it should be fixed now, deferred, or marked status-wontfix.  That analysis is the next step in the process."
On the other hand, that's sort of a subset of status-review.  It might create more confusion by adding another tag into the mix of tags that need to be managed, eliminating any of that intuitive sense of what tag to use that you're trying to create here.

I'm in favor of deletion, though it wasn't the focus of this particular post. Later today I'm planning to go through the posts in [status-reproduced] network-wide and determine whether they are correctly classified. If there's nothing left over when I'm done, I may end up recommending deletion internally. (If you object to deletion for any reason, please do let me know here.)

I've reclassified all [status-reproduced] posts network-wide into other states. A couple trickier ones but nothing really caught me off guard. Nearly all belonged in other states anyway. So I'm going to recommend that it be removed when [status-wontfix] changes over.

There should be a tag for when a post has been subsequently reviewed by a staff member after being escalated
When a post is tagged status-review, the next possible tags as you mention are either an outcome tag or one of the tags status-planned or status-deferred. There's still a gap here: if a moderator (not staff member) has escalated a request using the first tag, a staff member has to review it and decide whether it's worth planning it for implementation or deferring it for later. This decision requires staff to review over the request fully, which may take time for some requests.
In fact, this explains the former usage of the tag before the 2020 introduction of the escalation process (taken from its extended tag wiki):

There are multiple factors that may leave a report under review. There could be consideration of whether the proposed feature or bugfix is feasible or useful. There could be investigations on the complexity of the necessary solution. [...] Site developers may provide additional comments to request more information or to provide status updates as appropriate to the status of the review, until such time as the decision for approval or decline is made.

There's also a similar situation where a non-developer staff member (e.g., CM or support staff) escalates a report, but then a developer has to reproduce it and review over its complexity.
To summarize, once the tag has been applied, there's no way for people to know whether a (relevant) staff member has actually reviewed it. For all we know, it could just be hanging in the ticketing system. In fact, there are many posts that have had the tag for years - are they really taking long for staff to review, or are they just somehow getting passed over in the ticketing system?

The tag status-reproduced was useful in that it did provide some such window for bug reports. It basically stated that a developer had reviewed over the report and was able to reproduce it on their end, and that they're evaluating how complex it is to fix it. In fact, before I started writing this answer, I meant it as an argument towards retaining it, but as I started writing this, I realized that the same window is also valuable for feature requests.
One possible way to resolve this issue is to make a new tag status-escalated or status-ticketed for escalating reports (the post has been added to the ticketing system but has not been reviewed by relevant staff yet), and repurpose status-review for its originally-created purpose and that of status-reproduced (a relevant staff member is reviewing or has reviewed over the request - and if a bug, managed to reproduce it - and is making a decision on its subsequent outcome). There may be other ways too.

You cite the old definition for [status-review], but it's worth keeping in mind that it was almost never used. And the posts that were sent to [status-review] were typically never brought back for further consideration. It actually had a worse recall rate than [status-deferred], even. There's a very good reason for that.

Only a subset of employees have the ability to make decisions about backlog prioritization. Once a decision is made, then the post should ideally be moved to planned, deferred, or a terminal state. Before a decision-maker makes a decision, there's little value in notifying community members that a staff member looked at the post but decided they can't decide anything yet and need to review further. This function does have value, but it is very exceptional. For example, if an issue is at the forefront of community focus but we aren't able to act, we can acknowledge it with a comment.

This proposal is also not risk-free. If the expectation is that a staff member who looks over a post moves it from "escalated" into "review" if they're not able to make a decision (the typical case), that puts the staff member in the position of becoming the de facto point of contact for that issue, even when they have no authority to triage or prioritize that issue. After all, in the community's eye, they're now the one who knows the most about it - even if this is wrong! They may know very little (or nothing!) even after "reviewing" the post. They are not the expert by virtue of review.

Put another way, the problem you're raising is not solved with a tag. It is, fundamentally, a response time issue, not a tagging issue. It takes time to properly evaluate an issue and determine whether it should see work now, later, or not at all. If that occurred more reliably, then the need for an "I looked at this post" tag would be moot. Yes, many posts have been sitting in such a state for years. But we have not secretly made a decision about those posts and failed to communicate it, & they would not move faster with a new tag. We have simply not made a decision about those posts.

To answer your question in your last comment (I didn't see you deleted it since comment edits or deletions aren't auto-loaded), the value of knowing that staff have actually looked at the internal ticket in question is that I know that the request hasn't simply been ignored after being escalated internally. It helps signify progress with the issue and alleviate uncertainties of whether the ticket was reviewed internally after being escalated by a volunteer moderator. This is especially true if it's been a very long time since a ticket was escalated by a moderator and hasn't seen action since.

Gotcha. Then from the other side, I can tell you that every single post that enters [status-review] is read and reviewed by a Community Manager within one week of entering that state, typically sooner. Generally the purpose of this review is to find the right team to take on that work, and forward the request so that they may prioritize it. But we audit for high-priority work, and that is always (or nearly so) complete within a week.

@Slate As far as the point of contact issue, that can be easily resolved by using a generic "staff" role account. There are many other reasons for doing so, as noted in the answers and comments there, such as not having to worry about posts deleted for legal or privacy reasons being undeletable once the staff member who processes the request ceases to work for SE.

Yeah, for sure. A generic staff account is an option we've considered, but isn't something we can do right now. It solves some problems, creates some others, bit of a technical trade there we need to sit down and really think through.

@Slate Is there anything that prods staff to look at old tickets with no activity in a specific past period (e.g., year)?

That's a good question, and I'm unfortunately going to have to defer to a future discussion on that one. The nominal answer is that this is governed by the status-review SLA reporting process but for a variety of reasons, all I can say here is "wait and see." :)

Slate doesn't say it specifically but... the status-review tag means that the issue has been "ticketed"/"escalated". Failing an outage of some sort, the tag creates the ticket. I agree that in most cases, a comment is probably a better (and clearer) explanation of status than using a tag.

Agreed. A status tag wouldn't communicate anything in this particular case that wouldn't be better addressed by a comment, if there is some sort of update to share.

@Slate To add/explain: if there's no staff activity on a post, it looks outwardly like staff haven't seen it, even though there's an internal ticketing system in which they've seen it. See this Tim Post post: Just like in messengers when you see a contact light up? Well, bug reports need to light up or blink when someone's actively doing something with them, same for features. The lack of that actively contributes to a [false] perception that we don't see them (we do...

See also this Medium post from Monica Cellio (the case there is wholly different, but the same general thing applies): internal channels do nothing for the public record. (@V2Blast - see the above comment too)

@Slate Then theres a problem with your definition of status review as 'not been evaluated'. From an external point of view, if a member of the community team has read and reviewed it, then it has been 'evaluated' by a staff member, and no longer meets the definition of status-review. But it also may not be ready for any outcome tag.

@Slate From a communication point of view, it would be helpful to have something to distinguish between 'we are actively moving towards an outcome', and 'this needs an investigation, please wait 6 to 8 weeks for resources to be available'.

@user1937198 That sounds like what status-deferred is for?

Wontfix is a bit of an interesting one - what might be an example of the sort of bug that's annoying enough to get into the system but innocuous enough to let scurry around the codebase?

People report all sorts of really minor stuff, like "Changing the Title of the Post Does Not Change the Title of the Tab" (to the extent that it's reporting that it doesn't change until you reload; the actual bug report turned out to be confused about how tags are rendered in the page title) or possibly Inconsistencies on notification banner themes (to the extent that that's a bug; I marked it bydesign).

I don't have prepared examples so forgive me if these aren't the best choices. I found four that look like reasonable candidates: example one, example two, example three, example four. In all four, we broadly said that the bug is legit but we're just not going to do it. While the reasons vary, in general, bugs like these are too low ROI to fix (low impact, complicated fix).

SE have also had a bunch of events in which reported bugs/features/support questions were only relevant while the event was active, and just aren't relevant to the long-term network. Stuff like the April fools reskins of SO, hatdash/winterbash etc.

Why is status-deferred a process tag? It seems to be both an outcome and a process step. It's been reviewed, confirmed to be a problem, there's interest in fixing it, but it's not going to happen in the short term and there may not be a good approximation of when it will be finished.
Which brings me to my next point. I don't understand the introduction of status-wontfix. Specifically, it's not clear how this is distinct from status-declined or status-deferred. I think that using status-deferred addresses all of the problems with using status-declined without introducing a new tag - it lets people know that it's legitimate but there's not currently enough reason or resources to go after fixing it.
How do these fit into support requests? Things that aren't feature or bug requests. Questions about policies, for example. There's nothing other than status-completed so would we expect every policy question to be answered eventually, and move to either planned or deferred and then completed?
Saying that status-deferred shouldn't move to status-bydesign or status-norepro may not make sense. If something is deferred for months and years, other changes may invalidate it. When it comes out of deferred, someone may try to reproduce it and fail or design decisions confirm that the bug is actually what was desired all along.

Historically, [status-deferred] has sat in an ambiguous position: it  has not been clear whether the tag indicates work is still required and will be done at some point, or if it's being used to park an issue indefinitely. This change is purposefully breaking that ambiguity and treating [status-deferred] as requiring further work or decisionmaking. In other words, [status-deferred] should not be considered a terminal state. There is, therefore, "a need for staff attention on that report that has not yet been fulfilled."

Because [status-deferred] is solidly non-terminal, [status-wontfix] then differs from [status-deferred] in that it is terminal. While we could defer an issue and indefinitely leave it on the backlog, we may eventually make a purposeful decision that we are not going to fix that issue. Arguably, we should make a decision at some point, rather than kicking the can down the road indefinitely. (There are good process reasons for doing this. A big one -- a decision paves the way for the issue to be re-raised with modern reasoning as needed.)

Therefore, the deferred state may be used in the interim while ambiguities are resolved or if we believe an opportunity to work on an issue may open up. If it doesn't, deferred serves to indicate that we eventually have to make a decision about that post. [status-wontfix] is the terminal outcome corresponding to "no further action on this bug."

(A bit lower to the ground, mixing work that we want to do with work that we've decided we're not going to do anything about can lead to confusion when mapping out sprints and development plans, and can confuse users as to what our intentions are. Clean separation between issues we've already made decisions about and issues that really are still pending is important.)

Re your thought about policy questions - I don't think we've made an explicit decision about whether [status-review] is the appropriate pathway for those posts. We haven't gotten too many so far, and I'm not opposed, but I'm also not going to explicitly authorize that usage before I have the chance to discuss with the CM team as a whole. I think it can work, but I want to make sure that's how we want to do that kind of work.

@Slate Looking at the post, it is essential to address policy (or any other non-bug/non-feature request) question. The [tag:status-review] description says not to use it if the post cannot be handled by the process. That means we can no longer tag support questions, including policy questions, as status-review until the process is updated. So either that needs to change or the process needs to include policy and support questions before it happens

@Slate Thinking about it some more, I do think that status-wontfix is unnecessary. I can only see two terminal states: "the thing is done" or "the thing won't be done". Those map to status-complete and status-declined. Introducing two "the thing won't be done" states is unnecessarily complex. Anything that was declined can always be brought up again in the future and rereviewed.

Honestly, I suspect the easiest solution here is to make [status-declined] the terminal state for all non-bug requests (incl. support and discussion implicitly). I need to double check with a couple CMs first, but it does simplify the proposal: a pathway for bugs, a pathway for everything else.

RE wontfix - yeah, I went back and forth a lot on this for that reason. Yes, conceptually, there is "was done" and "will not be done." But I ultimately decided that the way it aids public communication, clarity, and education override the need to strip redundancies. (This is in part based on the internal friction folks have had with the status tag system, so it'll be hard to elaborate meaningfully here.)

@Slate From an end-user perspective, I find having wontfix and declines to be very confusing. I don't think it aids communication with me at all and only makes understanding the overall workflow for how requests are managed more difficult. In my experience, having divergent workflows and decision points makes things harder to understand and any elimination is often better.

I'll consider it. You might be right (like I say I've gone back and forth a lot on this too). But I'm comfortable trying this out anyway, because if it ends up being a mistake, we can merge [status-wontfix] into [status-declined], maybe rename [status-declined] if we want to, and call it a day.

It seems like status-deferred is a limbo tag which could eventually fall either way, and is not meant as a "go away" tag, so I'd agree that with the stated intent, it's a process tag.

I don't understanding the "Don't Use" copy for status-review, what would be an example of a post that as described cannot be handled by existing processes?

Do not use this tag if the post as described cannot be handled by existing processes

Would this just be things that are simply not bugs/features?

Most of these are requests for something other than a software change to the platform. For example, support requests typically shouldn't be brought in via [status-review] if the correct course of action is for the user to send in a Contact Us ticket. (Don't take this as a general rule. Exceptions exist.) However there are some really odd posts, like requests to build a whole product (!), that just don't fit within what the [status-review] process is for. Those shouldn't be sent in via [status-review], either.

That leaves, is there a process for the community to elevate a given, non-bug/feature, request to the team, or would we need to A: hope mods elevate it, or B: open a contact form with a link to the post, or,

@Slate Is it perhaps that it should be "can be handled by existing processes"? (e.g., can be handled by sending in a Contact Us ticket)

@RyanM Considering a sight reword to something like: "Do not use this tag if the post as described cannot be successfully handled by the status-review process," but it's a bit too circular for my tastes. I'll give it some thought.

@Slate I wonder if two separate "don'ts" would help clarify: one to cover the case of things that can be solved another way (e.g., requires moderator action rather than staff, should be handled through Contact us) and those that are too big in scope (but, how to define that? and also, without a process to handle those in some way, people will try to bend the system to fit anyways).

Maybe something like "Don't use if the post would need restructuring to be handled by existing processes"?

Just thought I'd add that the whole purpose for this seems to be clarity and understanding for everyone. So with that in mind, why not add an extra descriptor to the status outcome tags - another layer defining bugs and features?
Because, after all, the clearest tags are instantly definable to the observer. We can't expect everyone to spend half an hour reading and link-surfing posts for clarification - only for a deeper understanding if you're a great mod/user ;).
So things that aren't immediately obvious (if possible) need to be made so.
For example;
status-feature-declined
status-bug-bydesign
status-bug-nonrepo
status-bug-wontfix
Ideally, you shouldn't need to infer by contrast. Doing so could lead to misinterpretation and misuse. "But how do you decline a bug report..?" Well...
(btw, I don't think status tags are that hard to decipher once you know their collective purpose, it's pretty self-explanatory for the most part - especially for mods who just need to get things rolling. Their (our) only effective input being "to tag or not to tag". Complexity is the enemy of understanding, and understanding is the foundation of an efficient system. Simplicity.)
Just a thought :)


"Hey, wait, what’s up with that fifth thing? Where did that come from? And why is status-declined only for feature requests?"
Introduce status-wontfix

Except status-wontfix is only for bug reports, so it isn't a complete replacement.
What do we use for burninations and synonym requests (among other things) now that [status-declined] can't be used, and the newly introduced [status-wontfix] also can't be used?
Aside tag curation, certain support questions also get status labels, and now have no way to signal a declined status anymore. This particularly applies to requests for some moderation action against individual posts (specific-question, specific-answer, and various other support questions).

Do what ye will. This post (explictly) has nothing to say about how moderators should use status tags on per-site metas. "Non-goals of this post: Tell moderators how to use status tags. // Moderators use status tags differently than this - but clarifying this usage is under “non-goals of this post” above, so let’s set that aside."

Thomas Owens mentioned support requests here, and I'll redirect that inquiry there to avoid duplication. No need to catastrophize also - if there's an edge case that it seems this wasn't designed to cover, seriously, just do what seems right. I do want to get the process right, but I ain't holding y'all at knifepoint to follow my instructions step by step. I trust you to do what's right and be reasonably smart about it. (Though this doesn't change that this post doesn't say anything about what mods should or should not do.)

We should immediately merge status-declined and status-wontfix into a single one, useable no matter if it's a feature or a bug... Oh well, staff will just address that for the next "we-made-a-change-without-the-community-opinion" on meta tags in 6-8 years.

It feels like the tagging system as documented is very much leaning towards 'meta as a bug triage system' - Would these work similarly with feature requests ?

The process is intended to cover both bugs and feature requests. Good feature requests generally have more complicated journeys (and are honestly very hard to write), and it's harder to proscribe exactly what 'should' happen as they move through process, so the description is a bit looser by necessity. But still covered.
